# Scaling inside a TikZ matrix does not work?

Tags: tikz-pgf, scaling

I'm having some difficulty at scaling a TikZ draw inside a matrix:

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5]
    \matrix [yshift=2cm]{
       \draw (0,0)--(0.2,1)--(1,1.2)--(1.2,0)--(0,0);&
       \node{Some text that should not be scaled};\\
    };

    \draw (0,0)--(0.2,1)--(1,1.2)--(1.2,0)--(0,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see the same picture is scaled outside the matrix but not inside. I can't use the `scalebox` or `resizebox` methods because there is some text in my original picture that should not be scaled, as it happens by default when you scale via the TikZ own option.

So, why the draw does not scale inside the matrix? Is there some way I can make it scale without scaling the text too?

Comment: Did you try putting `scale` as an option for matrix too?

Comment: @JLDiaz tried now, doesn't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is one of those grey areas about cell picture issues. One not-super-clean solution is to set the transformation yourself.

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5]
    \pgfgettransform\mytrafo
    \matrix [yshift=2cm,execute at begin cell=\pgfsettransform\mytrafo]{
       \draw (0,0)--(0.2cm,1cm)--(1cm,1.2cm)--(1.2cm,0)--cycle;&
       \node{Some text that should not be scaled};\\
    };

    \draw (0,0)--(0.2,1)--(1,1.2)--(1.2,0)--(0,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great! Can't wait to mix up `\pgfsettransform` and  `\pgfgettransform` as I just did while testing with my real picture :D

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to using `\pgfgettransform` and `pgfsettransform` as suggested in the accepted answer, you can also explicitly transform every cell of the table as follows:

```
\matrix [yshift=2cm, every cell/.style={scale=0.5}]{
   \draw (0,0)--(0.2cm,1cm)--(1cm,1.2cm)--(1.2cm,0)--cycle;&
   \node{Some text that should not be scaled};\\
};
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!